# Origin of the adjective 답답하다

Tags: word-origin

답답하다 : Be in state of not going forward, because he is in his
logic pond.

너 답답하다 You are in trouble state or you are pitiful.

답 is an answer so that 답답하다 means that even though there is an
answer, we do not know the answer (This is someone's joke). This is an
origin of 답답하다 ?

Comment: One of the earliest, if not the earliest, appearance of that word is found in [救急方諺解](https://ko.wikisource.org/wiki/%EA%B5%AC%EA%B8%89%EB%B0%A9%EC%96%B8%ED%95%B4) published in 1466.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

답답하다 has two meanings so that there are two origins (cf. First
one may be in droooze's link)

1) There is no way to proceed :

There is a vocabulary "첩첩산중", whose meaning is 답답한 상태(**no way out of**
 it). But the direct translation is "surrounded by many mountains".

In ancestor-language of Korean, a mountain is "thaba" so that its
pronunciation is changed into 답.

2) It describes "state surrounded by things" :

When we wear a swimming uniform, then the suit gets stuck to (들러
붙다) our body so that we are **stuffy** (답답한)

Here pronunciation of 들러 붙다 is changed into 답답 하다.